# How to read data from tap interface?

Tags: networking, network-interface, tap

I have a problem with network bridges and tun/tap devices.

Actually, the main problem is that I am trying to create a network bridge and a tap interface before compile time. And in compile time my code needs to use the interface.
In my project code, `the Contiki` (https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki) code is compiled and it is used to create tap interfaces and communication.

If I run my source code with `sudo` command, everything is okay but as I said I need to create tap interface before and I should run the code without `sudo` command.

So if my code is running with `sudo` command, `ifconfig tap0` response is like the following;

```
tap0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fc00::231  prefixlen 7  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::cc9f:ddff:fe50:7d9a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether ce:9f:dd:50:7d:9a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 50  bytes 12195 (12.1 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 52  bytes 7869 (7.8 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

And in this state, my project runs well.

But I am trying to create tap interface with the following commands;

```
sudo ip tuntap add mode tap tap0 user myusername
sudo ifconfig tap0 up
sudo ip link set tap0 up
sudo ip -6 address add fc00::231/7 dev tap0
sudo ip address add dev tap0 scope link fe80::cc9f:ddff:fe50:7d9a
```

Then the `ifconfig tap0` response;

```
tap0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::cc9f:ddff:fe50:7d9a  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fc00::231  prefixlen 7  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 06:ea:8d:0e:66:74  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

So after this modifications in my Contiki code is trying to read tap0 interface

`ret = read(fd, uip_buf, UIP_BUFSIZE);`

but ret value is -1.(It returns an int value when it runs with sudo)
 I think if I am able to change tap0 interface's status as `RUNNING` maybe I can get ret value but I don't know how to do it.

Is there anyone knows how should I do?

NOTE:tapdev6.c modifications

```
void
tapdev_init(void)
{
  printf("INIT TAP DEV!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! \n");
  net_fd = open(DEVTAP, O_RDWR);
  if(net_fd == -1) {
    perror("tapdev: tapdev_init: open");
    return;
  }

#ifdef __linux
  {
    memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));
    ifr.ifr_flags = IFF_TAP|IFF_NO_PI;
    printf("INIT0 net_fd %d \n", net_fd);
    if (ioctl(/*net_fd*/4, TUNSETIFF, (void *) &ifr) < 0) {
        printf("INIT FAIL \n");
      perror("Unable to init tunnel interface\n");
      //exit(1);
    }
    printf("INIT1 net_fd %d \n", net_fd);
    ioctl(/*net_fd*/4, SIOCGIFHWADDR, &ifr);
    printf("INIT2 net_fd %d \n", net_fd);
  }
  /* Linux (ubuntu) */
char buf[256];
     snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "ip link set tap0 up");
     system(buf);
     PRINTF("%s\n", buf);
     snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "ip -6 address add fc00::231/7 dev tap0");
     system(buf);
     PRINTF("%s\n", buf);
     snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "ip -6 route add fc00::0/7 dev tap0");
     system(buf);
     PRINTF("%s\n", buf);

  /* freebsd */

    //try to set hw address
     // 12:bc:34:76:c9:2f
    ifr.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[0] = 0x12;
    ifr.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[1] = 0xbc;
    ifr.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[2] = 0x34;
    ifr.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[3] = 0x76;
    ifr.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[4] = 0xc9;
    ifr.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[5] = 0x2f;
  printf("Lan device %s\n", ifr.ifr_name);
  printf("LAN HW addr %02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X\n",
          (unsigned char)ifr.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[0],
          (unsigned char)ifr.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[1],
          (unsigned char)ifr.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[2],
          (unsigned char)ifr.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[3],
          (unsigned char)ifr.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[4],
          (unsigned char)ifr.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data[5]);
#endif /* Linux */

  lasttime = 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-ESUDO`

Seriously, you should set the owner of the tap interface. Try to following:

```
ip tuntap add tap0 mode tap user USER
```

Where `USER` is the user who will read and write to the handle opened via `/dev/net/tun`. I suspect that it's not only the read that failed, but also the `ioctl(TUNSETIFF)`, but you didn't bother to check the return value.

Here is a simple `opentap(ifname)` function that should open a fd handle to a tap interface, provided that the user running it has the right permissions:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <linux/if.h>
#include <linux/if_tun.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int opentap(char *ifn)
{
    int fd;
    struct ifreq ifr = { 0 };
    if (snprintf(ifr.ifr_name, sizeof ifr.ifr_name, "%s", ifn)
            >= sizeof ifr.ifr_name) {
        errno = ENAMETOOLONG; return -1;
    }
    if ((fd = open("/dev/net/tun", O_RDWR)) == -1) return -1;
    ifr.ifr_flags = IFF_TAP | IFF_NO_PI;
    if (ioctl(fd, TUNSETIFF, &ifr) == -1) {
        int e = errno; close(fd); errno = e; return -1;
    }
    return fd;
}
```

Comment: Yes. I am skipping 'ioctl(fd, TUNSETIFF, (void *) &ifr) < 0' because ioctl wants to root rights.Is it could be the reason for my problems?

Comment: You cannot skip that, as that's the call which is tying the file descriptor to the interface. Otherwise how could the kernel know that a write to `/dev/net/tun` should go to `tap0` or `tap1`? So, first you should create (as root) the `tap0` interface as owned by your user (see the command from my answer), and  then (as a regular user) open `/dev/net/tun` and tie the fd to `tap0` with `TUNSETIFF`. Then you could read and write packets to it.

Comment: I attached my tapdev6.c modifications and edited command list as you said. But still, it prints 'INIT FAIL' and my tap0 interface is not in RUNNING state.

Comment: @SayMyName You should fill `ifr.ifr_name` with the right interface name; otherwise the `TUNSETIFF` will fail with `EPERM` if run as a normal user, or create another *nonpersistent* interface if run as root (and give it the first free name -- `tap2` if `tap0` and `tap1` are already taken). Also, it would help if you were using `strerror` or `warn` or `err`, instead of printing things like `"INIT FAIL"` ;-)

Comment: @SayMyName `char *name = "tap0"; ... if(snprintf(ifr.ifr_name, sizeof ifr.ifr_name, "%s", name) >= sizeof ifr.ifr_name) [die with "name too long"]` in case you wonder how to do that.

Comment: @SayMyName I've added an example to my answer; it's part of a little wrapper program that I'm using with a lot of emulators that I've hacked to support networking through a simple fd in the the same way qemu can do with its `-net tap,fd=FD` option.

Comment: Thank you so much @pizdelect. As you say I set up tap0 interface but when I run the code without sudo it prints 'ifr_name' as tap1. I should change it as tap0. But it changes in 'ioctl' function. Is it correct way to set 'ifr_name' before the 'INIT0 net_fd print'  with 'char *name = "tap0"; ... if(snprintf(ifr.ifr_name, sizeof ifr.ifr_name, "%s", name) >= sizeof ifr.ifr_name)' code?

Comment: Setting the owner to the tap0 interface fixed my problem. Now I can use the ioctl command without the sudo. Thank you man.