# Understanding how virt-install connects the Ethernet interface in host machine with the Ethernet interface in the quest?

Tags: networking, qemu, libvirt

I installed Debian virtual machine with `virt-install` in a way that guest got one Ethernet interface named `vnet0`:

```
$ virsh domiflist git-server
Interface  Type       Source     Model       MAC
-------------------------------------------------------
vnet0      bridge     br-ext     rtl8139     52:54:00:a8:32:d7

$
```

This can be confirmed when inspecting the `qemu` command line:

```
-netdev tap,fd=27,id=hostnet0 -device rtl8139,netdev=hostnet0,id=net0,mac=52:54:00:a8:32:d7,bus=pci.0,addr=0x2
```

However, there is a TAP device in host machine with the same `vnet0` name:

```
$ ethtool -i vnet0                                                                                  
driver: tun
version: 1.6
firmware-version: 
expansion-rom-version: 
bus-info: tap
supports-statistics: no
supports-test: no
supports-eeprom-access: no
supports-register-dump: no
supports-priv-flags: no
$
```

..but with different MAC address:

```
$ ip l sh vnet0                                                                                     
56: vnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br-ext state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:54:00:a8:32:d7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
$
```

How exactly are the virtual-machine interface and the TAP device in host machine connected? Or is there only one TAP device? If yes, then how are the MAC addresses different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How exactly are the virtual-machine interface and the TAP device in host machine connected?

`qemu` (or a wrapper program that starts `qemu` or another simulator) first opens the `/dev/net/tun` device *multiplexer*. That returns a file descriptor,
which could be attached to a TAP interface by calling `ioctl(TUNSETIFF)` on that fd with the name of the TAP interface in the `ifreq->ifr.name` field.

That will fail if the TAP interface with that name was already attached in this manner.

The fd could be then used to write packets which will appear on the TAP interface as if received from the remote side, and read packets which were routed through the TAP interface by the kernel.

If the calling process has the `CAP_NET_ADMIN` capability (eg is `root`), and a TAP interface with that name does not already exist, it will be automatically created. If no name is given, the first free name will be used.

The fact that `/dev/net/tun` is a multiplexer means that an `open()` on it will return each time a handle to a different "remote half". And that "remote half" could be attached to a single TAP interface.

Also, just like any other file descriptor, that could be passed down to another program, if that program is able to use it in this way (as `qemu` is with its `-netdev tap,fd=FD` option).

See an example of a very simple `opentap` function in this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/499549/313992).

More details + sample code in the [tuntap.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/tuntap.txt) from the kernel documentation.

> Or is there only one TAP device? If yes, then how are the MAC addresses different?

No, there is a separate device for each client. The way you could connect multiple TAP devices to the same interface is by using a bridge on the host.

> However, there is a TAP device in host machine with the same vnet0 name ... ..but with different MAC address:

The interface on the host and that on the guest are completely different; think of it as of a virtual UTP cable -- with each device at both ends having its own MAC.

The `-device ...,mac=...` sets the hardware address of the emulated device on the *guest*, not of the TAP device on the host.

Comment: Thanks! So based on the output of my initial post, the `quemu` has created a `tap` interface named `vnet0` and `/dev/net/tun` returned a file descriptor `27` for that `vnet0` interface? And now the `qemu` connects the virtualized Ethernet adapter of guest with the `vnet0` interface in host machine with `-netdev tap,fd=27,id=hostnet0` command line option?

Comment: No, the program that started qemu (`virt-manager` ?) opened `/dev/net/tun`, did all the necessary setup (connected it to `vnet0`, etc) and then passed the open file descriptor to `qemu`, telling it that the fd is 27 via the `,fd=27` option (processes inherit open fds through fork and exec). Then `qemu` implements the emulated interface in the guest by ultimately writing and reading raw ethernet frames to that 27 fd. That's just one way to do it -- qemu also knows how to interface to `/dev/net/tun` itself.